# Is it possible to control multiple graphs simultaneously in visjs?

Tags: vis.js

I'm trying to recreate something like the weatherspark dashboard using visjs.  The screenshot below will illustrate that this allowed you to have multiple Y-axes each displayed adjacent to each other (vertically), allowing you to view multiple graphs next to one another:

[image]

Is it possible to do the same thing in vis.js, the framework I am using to display charts at the moment?  I want them "linked" so that a user controlling one chart (e.g. dragging the display, controlling zoom etc) affects all the charts simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not know visjs, and never heard about it, but I've just checked it.

As in most plugins like this, there are [events](http://visjs.org/docs/graph2d/#Events). Usually you can add a callback on events.

So if you want to do something, when a user change a range, you can do what in the documentation:

```
Graph2d.on('rangechanged', onChange);
```

Comment: Do you suggest capturing that event and then firing off the same event to each of the other graphs?